# How can I call Objective-C methods from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I want to display `SQLite` Data base content on  UIWebView. For that i have a local HTML file. On Body load in html file  calling JavaScript Function. Inside the Java Script how to call Objective-c method. how to get Data from Objective c to Java Srcipt.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- a script inline --> 
        <script language="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
            <!--
            function myJsFunc() 
            { 

                //here i want to call objective-c methods.

            } 
            // -->
            </script>
        </head>
    <Body Bgcolor=#800000 onload="myJsFunc(); return true;">

        </Body>
</html>
```

Objective-C  code 
......

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *path;
    NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"Demo" ofType:@"html"];

    // make a file: URL out of the path
    NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];
    [self.view addSubView:myWebView];
}
-(NSArray*)FetchingDataFromDataBase{

    // Code for retriving data from SQlite data Base, and return NSArray;
    return myArray;
}
```

Inside the Function `myJSFunc`(), how can call `-(NSArray*)FetchingDataFromDataBase.`

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Comment: The `language` attribute on `script` elements has been deprecated for more than a decade, you can leave it off now. The `type` attribute should be in lower case, but frankly, you [don't need it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-script-element.html#attr-script-type) unless you're including a script *not* written in JavaScript (this is one of the areas where the HTML5 spec is just codifying existing practice, rather than dictating something new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post given by graver explains it how to do it.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 
      shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
      navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

If you have the above method in your class, this method will be called before a new page is loaded.  Only if this method returns YES, the new load request is processed.  We use that mechanism to communicate back to the Objective-C functions.

Comment: Can i call Objective c Fuction from External Java Script