# Sharing data between UIWebView and UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developping an iOS application, witch contain many UIWebview, in one webView the user should input data, i would like to store this data in for example SQlite or Plist. can i have the data user input ( in the Webview) and use it in other parts of the application ( UIViewController). How to do this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to transfer user input in webview(HTML) to UIview (Objective-C), you need to do it in roundabout way.  Make use of the function:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 
  shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

See more details in the following post:

[How can I call Objective-C methods from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206793/how-can-i-call-objective-c-methods-from-javascript/10273889#10273889)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in many ways but the best I can think of right now is to run a JavaScript that return the value of that input you want.
I believe the method is

```
[instanceOfWebview stringByEvakuatingJavscriptFromString:"javascript_code_here"];
```

This will return the results of your JavaScript code as a string which you can receive into a variable.

Hope it helps!